# RequireJS doesn't load dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Problem:** 
require.js loads my modules as `undefine`s.

**Brief description:**
If you'd look at `main.js` file, you will see that it has `TodoItem` dependency. And it's `undefine`. The point also is that the body of `TodoItem` module is never called.

**Question:**
Why require.js doesn't execute `TodoItem` body and loads `undefine`?

**My structure:**

```
index.html
js/
 |-main.js
 |-app/
   |-TodoItem.js
 |-libs/
  |-backbone
  |-requirejs
  |-underscore
```

*main.js*

```
require([
    'app/TodoItem'
], function (TodoItem) {
   //PROBLEM: TodoItem is 'undefined'
});
```

*TodoItem.js*

```
define('TodoItem', [], function() {

    //Body is never called!

    var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        validate: function(attrs, options) {
            if (!attrs.todoMessage)
            return 'TodoItem without todo message';
        }
    });
    return TodoItem;
});
```

Comment: try moving `TodoItem.js` in `app/TodoItem/Todoitem.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*app/TodoItem.js*

```
define([], function() {
    // backbone model etc..
});
```

Don't name your module, requireJS will pick it up using the folder structure. In this case requireJS will pick it up from app/TodoItem.js.

If you use optimizer, it will automatically name it for you.

Comment: @V_B if it helped you should accept the answer, until you are not looking for a better solution. Otherwise it looks to other viewers that you are still waiting for answer.